# W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: python, cmd, gpu, amd-gpu

I am working on a AlexNet Python code, when I run the code, the first thing that comes up is the following error message:

```
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-04-27 00:47:14.117722: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-04-27 00:47:14.121489: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: JoshGarcia
2022-04-27 00:47:14.122508: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: JoshGarcia
```

I have a AMD Ryzen 7 3700U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, 2300 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s) with Microsoft Windows 11 Home OS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you try to install on WIndows, have you followed every step in this list: https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781 ?

Comment: @Noltibus - I see that is only for NVIDIA GPU, but I have AMD Ryzen. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an AMD graphics card and no Nvidia GPU, those messages are expected, since CUDA is a Nvidia framework.

YOu can try to follow this [guide](https://tealfeed.com/install-tensorflow-gpu-amd-gpus-vbs7s) to install GPU support for your Ryzen graphics card on windows or this [guid](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/install-tensorflow-2-for-amd-gpus-87e8d7aeb812) for Linux.